# How to find dict in a list of dict based on a value in a list?

Tags: python, algorithm, list

I have a list of dicts where each dict contains a list, here's an example:

```
[{ "1": [0,1,2,3]},{ "2": [4,5]},{ "3": [6,7,8,9,10,11]},{ "4": [12] }]
```

I'm struggling to build a function that would take a value as input and return the correspending key :

```
print(somefunc(12)) # Should print 4
print(somefunc(5)) # should print 2
```

I'm sure that each value in each list is unique, so I don't have to care about the case where I would have the same value in different lists.

What's the pythonic way to do this, I have tried to do some math logic by deviding the index over the sum and checks if it's smaller than 1, but with no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop over the list, then the dict items, then check the value and return the key if you find that value:

```
def somefunc(val):
    l = [{ "1": [0,1,2,3]},{ "2": [4,5]},{ "3": [6,7,8,9,10,11]},{ "4": [12] }]

    for dictionary in l:
        for key, v_list in dictionary.items():
            if val in v_list:
                return key
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[list(item.keys())[0] for item in ls if val in list(item.values())[0]]
```